# How to create a soap_dom_element to assign it to __any with gSOAP in C?

Tags: c, gsoap

I am trying to port these C++ line to C with gSOAP library:

```
trt__Capabilities *capabilities = ctx->getMediaServiceCapabilities(this->soap);
tds__GetServicesResponse.Service.back()->Capabilities->__any = soap_dom_element(this->soap, NULL, "trt:Capabilities", capabilities, capabilities->soap_type());
```

I thought this would do it but soap_dom_element cannot be used like this in the C gSOAP API

```
tds__GetServicesResponse->Service[1].Capabilities->__any = soap_dom_element(soap, NULL, "trt:Capabilities", capabilities, SOAP_TYPE__tds__Service_Capabilities);
```

Another thing I tried that compiles but crash at runtime

```
struct trt__Capabilities *capabilities = fillServiceCapabilities(ctx, soap);
char * tag = "trt:Capabilities";
char * type = "";
int id = -1;
soap_element_begin_out(soap, tag, soap_embedded_id(soap, id, capabilities, 
    SOAP_TYPE_trt__Capabilities), type);
void * elt =  soap_element_end_out(soap, tag);
soap_add_elt(&tds__GetServicesResponse->Service[1].Capabilities->__any, elt);
```

Please someone help me find the correct way to create a new dom element and assign it to a "struct soap_dom_element __any" object.

Thanks!

Comment: Is `soap_dom_element` a library function or a custom one?

Comment: @Azeem: It is from the gSOAP library in stdsoap2.h.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is simply set the `__any` member to a dynamically allocated DOM node with `soap_elt_new`:

```
tds__GetServicesResponse->Service[1].Capabilities->__any = soap_elt_new(soap, NULL, "trt:Capabilities”);
```

and then set the serializable "node" and "type" values of this DOM node to the serializable C `capabilities` data of type `tds__Service_Capabilities`:

```
soap_elt_node(tds__GetServicesResponse->Service[1].Capabilities->__any, capabilities, SOAP_TYPE__tds__Service_Capabilities);
```

This serializes `capabilities` as element `<trt:Capabilities>`.

See the gsoap [C DOM API documentation](https://www.genivia.com/doc/dom/html/index.html#c-api).

**EDIT**: I meant `soap_elt_node` rather than `soap_dom_node` as corrected above.

Comment: When I compile I get "undefined reference to `soap_dom_node'", also the C DOM API documentation does not mention soap_dom_mode.

Comment: This is the definition of _tds__Service_Capabilities, __any is not a pointer.

/* generated/onvif.h:1336 */
#ifndef SOAP_TYPE__tds__Service_Capabilities
#define SOAP_TYPE__tds__Service_Capabilities (175)
/* complex XML schema type 'tds:Service-Capabilities': */
struct _tds__Service_Capabilities {
        /** XML DOM element node graph */
        struct soap_dom_element __any;
};
#endif

Comment: I don't know if you have `__any` as a pointer in your C code because it depends on the configuration and soapcpp2 options used. If not, then just set the tag name first with `soap_elt_set()` and then the serializable contents with `soap_elt_node(&tds__GetServicesResponse->Service[1].Capabilities->__any, capabilities, SOAP_TYPE__tds__Service_Capabilities);` Again, just set the `__any` member.